Should there be a bot deletion reason?
Frequently there are answers or questions on the site which are clearly created by non-human accounts.
For example https://english.stackexchange.com/a/624403/418554
This is an "answer" to an 8 year old question by a new account with a full name and only a single post. This is very obviously not a real person or a real answer. Yet people in the comments engage with it in good faith as if it were a real person.
More examples:

https://english.stackexchange.com/a/624462/418554
https://english.stackexchange.com/a/624458/418554

None of the reasons for recommending deletion in the "Review queues" or when flagging the  post reflect the reality of the situation. It's bot spam and it's frequent.
There is also no way to flag the user.
Should there be a more direct way to flag this kind of spam which is frequent and unaddressed?


if we decide to ban all first answers from new accounts, then very likely there would stop being new accounts. 2. I think you vastly underestimate what humans are capable of. The examples seem like perfectly legitimate, if misguided, users. 3. What you're demonstrating is not "spam" by the SE definition, since it's not promoting anything.


"There is also no way to flag the user." just raise a custom mod flag, mention the user and why you think they are a problem. If the user has no post themselves, you can flag any post, even your own (it's probably the easiest) and put the explanation there.

Also, I have to wonder why are there three examples and each is deemed to be wrong (information from not just you here but also users who commented on the post) yet none of those answers are downvoted.

They are not downvoted because these are such old questions that nobody really stumbles on them.

The first example has four commenters. That excludes yourself - it's five total, otherwise. It's hardly undiscovered. One of the other two examples has two comments, the other has one comment. They have also been discovered. And it's the commenters claiming the answer is lacking or even completely wrong. I fail to see any reason for the lack of votes. They have been discovered, the users who discovered and commented on them have more than enough rep to downvote. Some have five digits of reputation.

EDIT: Not a bot. AI bots don't make capitalisation mistakes... or talk about an English region called  Surrey The reverse occurs in worry where i can hear it rhyme with Surrey. See also one of thecfactors that delayed the US entrance AI bots don't make those type of errors.

@Mari-LouA that is not correct

This is very obviously not a real person or a real answer. where's the evidence, the fact it is a new account, and the quality of their answer is arguably low? I've seen worse first answers in eleven years. And I've seen spammers who post comments two or three days later, when everything is calm, and add their spammy link in a comment.  Because posts are not bumped to the front page when a user or the OP posts a comment with or without an iffy  link. So, the suspect could be a spammer but there's nothing today that proves it indefinitely.

I would argue that the answer is nonsense and has all the hallmarks of a large language model generating random sentences after another according to some training set pattern. A missed space is especially indicative of this. They all follow a pattern. Why do they have full names? Why do they all have a single comment? Why do none of the comments make any sense in context? Why do they all answer ancient questions? This is not how human beings use the internet.

"Why do they have full names? Why do they all have a single comment? Why do none of the comments make any sense in context? Why do they all answer ancient questions?"  here is a plausible explanation that doesn't require nefarious reasoning: real people landed on those pages from an online search. Then they proceeded to post as anonymous user because they did find this topic thus have some sort of vested interest in it. The answer was them trying to add their thoughts. The name is information being asked when you post when unregistered.

Somebody being wrong doesn't always stop them from sharing what they think is relevant. Especially online.

It's been years that unregistered users post complete babble, use rude and crude language in answers to “ancient questions”, to then vanish into thin air never to be seen (at least not with the same account) again. Fairly normal behaviour, their answers get flagged and more often than not, their contributions get deleted. Users who use ChatGPT or Gemini to post answers still occur but less frequently than one or two years ago.

It's just so obvious to me that these can't be real people. If it isn't to you then I guess we don't agree on the fundamentals of this question. There is no way either side can prove their position.

Well, except we've been getting these kinds of posts for a very long time - long before ChatGPT was released. The sites also have a 10k tool to monitor for these called "new answers to old questions" (shortened to NATO - yes, without the last Q) because often such answers are bogus for any variety of reasons ("me too", or asking another question, or indeed trying to offer an answer which doesn't answer the question, etc). None in the three examples you've given seems out of place. People are people and they post wrong stuff. SE is a big network. It's visible online.

If these are indeed "bots" - what even is the end game? Spammers do some times post but fail to actually add in their spam. It's known to happen. I find it extremely unlikely the examples you gave are of that. Spammers rarely post unregistered. And when they do, they don't tend to post what is in the posts you've shown. You may say it's "obvious" to you but I fail to see how. No, it's not obvious. With the benefit of years of: using the network; looking for spam; looking for gen AI content - I can't see signs that the post are illegitimate. Can't be 100% certain but can be fairly sure

I don't think there is an endgame or even a general aim. That should not be the test for whether something is wrong. Generative models and automated bots just produce garbage with no purpose.

No, that's not correct. Bots are created by somebody. They don't appear ex nihilo and go posting. Gen AI is also not randomly posting. The people behind the bots have an aim. Except the rare cases where the aim is "test my bot" (which is usually a short phase), there is a motive - they might want to hurt the site, they might want to advertise, they might want to disseminate some (mis)information. Posting garbage for the garbage's sake is not something I've seen happen on a volume you are indicating. With that said, you seem to not want to take other views. If you just dismiss this again: bye

While it it is possible that we will at some point need a 'bot deletion reason', none of the examples in the question seem to be bot postings. They are more plausibly looked at as what is on this site a relatively old phenomenon, of somebody coming to a particular page without being familiar with the site's overall architecture, and then posting something prompted by what is on the page, that would be OK on a site that is more open to the contributors freely following such chains of associations, but not here. The not-an-answer flag already exists for dealing with such posts.

None of the three posts mentioned appears on its face to be per-se spam or GenAI content.
Remember that spam does not mean an answer that is merely incorrect or of low quality. Neither does spam mean that a post is unwanted or even that it is arrant nonsense or indecipherable gibberish, or that it is abusive of our users or of the system. We have other mechanisms already in place for all of those things, including the use of existing flagging reasons.
Spam here means something quite different from all these, something quite specific. The prevailing sense with which the word spam is used on the Stack Exchange network is clarified in the network FAQ on What are the “spam” and “rude or abusive” (offensive) flags, and how do they work? which reads in part:

What makes something spam and when should I flag it?
A post should be marked as spam only if it promotes a product, service, or similar; and is unsolicited or lacks disclosure of affiliation.
[...]
It should not be marked as spam when:

The post contains no useful information, such as an answer that says “I don't have any idea how to solve your problem”. Flag as not an answer instead.

It contains only gibberish, such as “sdhsgfdhsfdshs”. Consider using the rude or abusive flag for these cases - see below.


What makes something rude or abusive and when should I flag it?
A post should be marked as rude or abusive (formerly known as offensive) if it contains hate speech, obscenities, abuse against people, or abuse of the community or system, i.e., if the post is or contains a clear violation of the Code of Conduct.

Abuse of the system or community is everything that is created with the intention to harm them. This includes posts by users with no useful contributions to the site that contain no useful content at all – i.e. gibberish posts along the lines of:

asdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasd


As a rule of thumb, everything that would be out of place in polite discourse is rude or abusive.



As for the allegation that these postings are ones whose contents were produced via generative AI backed by some large learning model, I see no evidence that this is so. I instead see some evidence that they were written by humans unassisted by the same; for example, the one that was edited, as mentioned in the comments. I also see no private internal evidence available only to moderators that these user accounts are in any way linked to one another.
That does not mean they are decidedly not any of those things. It means only what I said: that I myself have so far been unable to bring to light any evidence supporting these allegations.
The community should continue to treat them with existing mechanisms for dealing with normal posts, things like adding a comment suggesting improvements or asking for clarification, by downvoting, by voting for deletion, or where merited flagging as very low quality or not an answer.
These do not appear to be abusive or commercially connected posts. If you believe them to be secretly AI-generated posts created by non-human actors in contravention of our site’s policy against these, simply flag them with a custom moderator flag to that effect and give us explicit details of exactly why you believe this so that we can review your evidence privately.
It is not constructive to argue about a post’s possible GenAI provenance in public comments. Better simply to flag for moderator attention as explained above, then move on.
